# BullMQ start Job from file with IIFE

Tags: javascript, node.js, child-process, iife, bullmq

Let's say I have a `function1.js` (or `ts`, it doesn't matter in this case),`function2.js` and any other files which are IIFE with different logic, like that:

```
(async function F() {
  try {
    //[1,2,..n].map(x => console.log(x));
    //await any other action 
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e)
  }
})()
```

and I have any job queue manager, in my case, it's [BullMQ](https://github.com/taskforcesh/bullmq), but I guess it's relevant for [Bull](https://github.com/OptimalBits/bull) or [Agenda](https://github.com/agenda/agenda). So the question is, can I put in the queue the files themselves?

So in the case of starting a new Worker, it will self-execute itself?

Like this:

```
const worker = new Worker(queueName, async (job: Job) => {
    // `path/to/functionN.js`
    return 'some value';
});
```

I understand that queue are created for the cases when one typical function requires args, which should be passed by MQ to do the routine tasks. But in this case, I have various `function.js` files and want to do managing the queue for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a [relative example in BullMQ docs](https://docs.bullmq.io/guide/workers/sandboxed-processors). Actually, it's called sandbox processors, and only Bull and BullMQ, among any others job queue managers support such feature.

Other, you'll need to write your own implementation.

The alternative is using [pm2 programmatic API](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/pm2-api/) which would manage files manually. In that case, you pass a direct path to file with IIFE, and then it has been executed via pm2.

```js
    const worker = new Worker('Queue', async (job: Job) => {
      /**
       * job.data is path to file
       * not sure that await before pm2 is nessessary
       */
      console.log(job.data)
      await pm2.connect(err => {
        if (err) console.error(err)
        pm2.start({
          name: 'Task Name',
          script: job.data.path,
          exec_mode: 'cluster',
        }, (err) => {
          if (err) console.error(err)
          pm2.disconnect()
        });
      });
    }, {connection: connectionRedis});
```

In that case, you are able to monitor your task via `pm2 -list command`

> *If you are using TypeScript in your project, then don't forget that path should be to the compiled JS file, otherwise configure pm2 correctly*